# Сортировка поверх группировки LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется коллекция с данными. Я пишу к ней следующий запрос:

```
var rezult = Должники
    .GroupBy(x => ((x.num-1)/36).ToString())
    .Select(x => new { a = x
                          .Select(y => new { y.dolg, y.num, y.fam })
                          .OrderByDescending(y=>y.dolg)
                          .Take(3),
                       b = x.Key});
```

Он работает, я получаю часть решения. Мне нужно этот запрос отсортировать по убыванию поля dolg. Я пытался в конец добавить конструкцию типа:

```
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.a)
```

Но, тогда я получаю исключение "По крайней мере в одном объекте должен быть реализован интерфейс IComparable." Как мне тогда выполнить сортировку без учета ранее сделанной группировки?
Дополнение

```
List<Должник> Должники = new List<Должник>();
Должники.Add(new Должник(58.7, "Карапузова", 5));
Должники.Add(new Должник(34.5, "Чуприн", 10));
Должники.Add(new Должник(58.7, "Карапузова", 5));
Должники.Add(new Должник(34.5, "Чуприн", 10));
Должники.Add(new Должник(64.1, "Большова", 25));
Должники.Add(new Должник(54.6, "Бурцев", 15));
Должники.Add(new Должник(21.3, "Беленкова", 30));
Должники.Add(new Должник(87.9, "Сырова", 37));
Должники.Add(new Должник(27.9, "Малец", 42));
Должники.Add(new Должник(54.6, "Бакарчук", 86));
Должники.Add(new Должник(58.7, "Макарова", 90));
Должники.Add(new Должник(34.5, "Калашникова", 100));
Должники.Add(new Должник(64.1, "Мосин", 97));
Должники.Add(new Должник(54.1, "Драгунов", 107));
```

Сам класс Должник также реализован и содержит поля:

```
public double dolg;
public String fam;
public int num;
```

То что я имею на данный момент без ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно чтобы сортировка срабатывала по полю долг

Comment: Что такое dolg? Это какой-то класс или значение?

Comment: приведи пример данных. У тебя в каждом элементе есть несколько значений  dolg,  и в разных элементах значения могут по разному пересекаться, поэтому непонятно как ты хочешь отсортировать например `[1,5,10]` c `[2,3,15]`?

Comment: @iluxa1810, это значение

Comment: @Grundy я привел пример данных. Суть в том, что я группирую по полю num (это значение подъезда должника, далее я использую его при выводе). Но в финальном выводе у меня должники должны быть отсортированы в порядке уменьшения значения поля dolg

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.a.dolg)` ?

Comment: это действие и приводит к ошибке описанной мной

Comment: то есть ты хочешь объединить группы и отсортировать?

Comment: @Александр 1) В вопросе у вас другое действие

Comment: 2) Ваш пример данных не очень хорош, потому что все две строки с данными, это как-то мало, для того чтобы показать результат работ группировки

Comment: 3) Не помешал бы пример результата, т.к. трудно понять что нужно получить в итоге

Comment: 4) `(x.num-1)/36` я надеюсь вы в курсе, что бывает когда int на int делишь

Comment: @4per, 1) Если я пишу как вы предложили, то он сразу ругается на поле dolg
2) Данные я добавил, сейчас в них 3 группы
4) Да, в данном случае этого достаточно, мне не нужна дробная часть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы необходимо было воспользоваться функцией SelectMany

```
var rezult = Должники.GroupBy(x => ((x.num - 1) / 36+1).ToString())
    .Select(x => new {
         a = x.Key,
         b = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.dolg).Take(3)})
    .SelectMany(x => x.b, (l, d) => new { 
         podr = l.a, fam = d.fam, dolg = d.dolg, num = d.num})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.dolg);
```